# infinite scroll manual trigger

Tags: jquery, wordpress, triggers, infinite-scroll

Just doesn't seem to work... :-( Have seen more complaints about it but I can't find the answer.

**The Problem:**
Infinite scroll works but not the manual trigger.
When I click the link, nothing happens.
Firebug gives

[Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

**My code:**

```
    <?php echo ('<ul id="infinite">'); ?>
<?php 
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('paged='.$paged.'&cat=5&showposts=3&meta_key=video_video&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC'  . $post->ID);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_video', true) ) : ?>
    <li class="video"><?php $home = array("h" => 290, "w" => 380, "zc" => 1, "q" =>100);
            //echo get('video_video');
            echo ('With: ');
            echo get('participant_first_name');
            echo ('&nbsp;');
            echo get('participant_last_name');
            echo ('</li>');?>

<?php endif;?>


<?php endwhile;?>

<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_video', true) ) { ?>
    <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
        <nav id="nav-below" >
        <div id="next" >
        <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Scroll down for more', 'intowntheme' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; //end nav ?>
<?php } else {  ?>
<p>There are no interviews at the moment </p>
<?php }   ?>     
</ul>
```

**And my script:**

```
jQuery('ul#infinite').infinitescroll({ 
    navSelector  : "#next",  // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector : "#next a",   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : "ul#infinite li",  // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    errorCallback: function() { 
          // fade out the error message after 2 seconds
          $('#infscr-loading').animate({opacity: 0.8},2000).fadeOut('normal');   
        },   
    loading         : {
         msgText: "<em>Loading the next year of Grantees...</em>",
        finishedMsg: "<em>You've reached the end of the Interviews.</em>"
    },
  });

  //kill scroll binding
    jQuery(window).unbind('.infscr');
    //setTimeout("jQuery('#next').slideDown();", 1000);
     //hook up the manual click guy.

    jQuery('#next a').click(function(){
        jQuery('#next a').infinitescroll('retrieve.infscr');
     return false;
    });
```

**also tried**

```
jQuery(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
```

**instead of**

```
jQuery('#next a').infinitescroll('retrieve.infscr');
```

**but no luck.**

Firebug then says *`trigger(retrieve.infscr) called incorrectly`*

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Pfoe, found it... Long live good documentation (NOT with this plugin!)

**This:**

```
 jQuery('#next a').click(function(){
    jQuery('#next a').infinitescroll('retrieve.infscr');
 return false;
});
```

**Should be:**

```
jQuery('#next a').click(function(){
    jQuery('ul#infinite').infinitescroll('retrieve');
 return false;
});
```

the biggest problem was the .infscr which shouldn't be there..
Hope it helps someone else..

**Documentation-like solution:**

```
jQuery("#clickable_element").click(function(){
    jQuery('#main_content_container').infinitescroll('retrieve');
        return false;
});
```

**Note:**
You may have to add the [manual trigger behavior](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/behaviors/manual-trigger.js) if you are working with masonry or isotope in order to make it work. Just include `manual-trigger.js` after infinitescroll and pass the behavior by passing `behavior: 'twitter'` when calling the plugin.

Comment: I'd keep shooting myself in the foot all day long if it wasn't for this post!

Comment: "Long live good documentation (NOT with this plugin!)." Agree 100%

Answer (score 1):

I made the following tweak to ensure the navigation link showed up after being clicked the first time:

```
jQuery("#clickable_element").click(function(){
    jQuery('#main_content_container').infinitescroll('retrieve');
    jQuery('#pagination').show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Divot, is there a way of hiding the button when there are no more posts? If I do what you have suggested, the button will show all the time even with no more posts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...
$('#next a').click(); 
?

Comment: No I wish it was that simple, everything else in my script only loads with jQuery(document).ready(function(){ } function. And the infinite scroll does work (which proves jQuery instead of $) just not the manual trigger.

Comment: seems this should work... jQuery('ul#infinite').infinitescroll('retrieve')

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps editing your original answer as .click() does NOT work. and a Maybe... answer is unhelpful. I prefer not to down vote or edit myself, so please edit.